# how to refactor anonymous function in npm using browserify

Tags: javascript, npm, refactoring, browserify, anonymous-function

Learning npm with browserify.

I would like to refactor a code I wrote in modules.

For the sake of learning, I am trying to break it down little by little.

So far I have something like:

on index.html

```
<body onload=example.main()>
```

and on my javascript:

```
(var example = function() {

     var helper = function (){
           // smtg
     }
     // body: 
     // body is made by global objects, functions that I will then return on traps, e.g. main and helper. I would like now to separete functions and body in dedicated modules, to tide a bit the code

     return {
         main :  function() {
             // show main UX
         },
         helper : helper
     }
})()
```

The first thing I want to do, is to export the function as a module, so that I can call example.main() on my index page.

I would like to start separate functions and "body", and then exports only traps I want in my example object.

I tried:

```
module.export = function () {
   return example
}

var example = function() { ...} // no more calling the anonymous function
```

but got error example.main is not a function

and other attempts to export my example(), I cannot.

Is it maybe because it is not a constructor?
Could you help to show a syntax and logic of a first example to export only the traps I want from example ( main, helper) and how would you refactor helper, main, and "body" in three different npm modules ?

Comment: show us how you are importing this function.

Comment: I copied that anonymous function in index.js. I am running `npm start` with browserify (in package.json is defined as `"start": "node_modules/.bin/browserify -s example ./app/index.js > ./app/bundle.`)